# How can I make only the actual text and not the background of a hyperlink in javascript be clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

I have an `a href` inside a div, and this link inside a table cell is multiline and text-align centered.

Now the whole cell becomes clickable, since the a href is filling the whole space except a little area closest to the border. I want the area around the link-text to not be clickable, and only the text.

this is the css:

```
tbody td.link a{
    display: inline;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #545454;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 4px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Since the z-index is 10, then the link is "closer to the user" than the background, and if I change this the whole link is disabled. 
I also tried this, but without result:

```
$('td.link').find('a').click(function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            ev.stopPropagation();

        });
```

Summary: Is there a way to make only the actual text characters of a link clickable, and not the background?
THanks!

Comment: Can you throw in an extra div or span around the link and style that one instead of making the link box itself bigger?

Comment: Well, I don't want to make the text field bigger. But I could make the text aligned to the left instead of centered, and that would create an extra area, a "corner" of the link field without text. But as it is now, the clickable area extends to the whole field, even the area without text.

Comment: Padding is clickable, change padding-top to margin-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot, because the actual text does not constitute an element. An element always contains some empty space around the characters (not to mention their inside). But you can limit the area occupied by the element. This may mean removing its padding, setting its line height to a smaller value (maybe 1), and changing a block element to an inline element. For more specific advice, you need to provide more specific information (HTML and CSS code).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is what I am doing right now, playting with the line height, position, padding and margins.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have a problem with the padding:4px

since padding is part of the element, it becomes clickable. I would suggest, using margin, 
or padding on the parent element. (you could use box-sizing:border-box, to solve any sizing problems.)

Answer (score 0):

You add this style

```
tbody td.rank a{
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: No, that only changes the appearance of the text-line, it doesn´t affect the background area?